# Limitations of OpenShift Origin

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-enterprise

Are there any enforced limitations on OpenShift Origin compared to OpenShift Container Platform (former Enterprise)? I mean, things like on Origin you can only have up to a certain (low) number of nodes, etc.

Also, which features are available in the Container Platform but not so in Origin? Of course, besides support...

Regards,
Luiz

Comment: Did you find out? I am researching the same.

Comment: I believe kumar answer below is mostly correct. One thing: the free version can be slightly ahead as it may contain some enhancements that are not yet fully validated for the paid offering.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any difference except support stuff.

Once in  a while Enterprise version is branched out  of origin and thoroughly verified. that's it.

If they figure out any bug, it will be posted in origin as well.